# TestNG Framework and new Keyword

Tags: java, testng

I'm new to the TESTNG framework. In this framework there is no main method. Hence my doubt is, can we use the new keyword to create object anywhere in the test suite? Or is there a basic rule that objects can be instantiated only at some places (like within, testng annotations like @beforesuite, @test and others)?

And in the below code when I used new keyword (Ideal objIdeal = new Ideal();) inside the class it fails but when I put it inside the @test annotation method(login or logout), it passes. Hence what is the basic thumb rule to instantiate objects in classes while using a Testng framework.

```
package testing.ideal;

public class Application {

    public String strURL;

    public Application() {
        this.strURL = Ideal.strURL;
        System.out.println("the url is--" + this.strURL);
    }

}
```

---

```
package testing.ideal;
        import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class Ideal
        extends Application {
    public static String strURL = "XXX";
    Ideal objIdeal = new Ideal();

    @Test
    public void login() {
        System.out.println("This is an testng Method");
    }

    @Test
    public void logout() {
        System.out.println("This is an testng Method");
    }

}
```

---

```xml
/* This is Testng XML*/
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel = "none">
    <test name="login" >
        <classes>
            <class name="testing.ideal.Ideal">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: You need to run test classes with a dedicated runner class; it is very unclear what your environment is

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotation :

`@BeforeSuite/@AfterSuite` To run some logic before/after all tests in a particular suite will run.

`@BeforeMethod/@AfterMethod` To run some logic before/after each test method.

`@BeforeGroups\@AfterGroups` To run some some before/after the first/last test method that belongs to the group

`@BeforeTest\@AfterTest` To run some logic before/after any test method that are enclosed in `<test>`

So in your test class, create a method for e.g. `setUp` to create an instance of `objIdeal`

```
 @BeforeTest
  public void setUp()
  {
     objIdeal = new Ideal();  
  }
```